# JSON not allowing :\

Tags: javascript

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rRuHm/)

```
alert('How do i make abspath==U:\\path?'); //shouldnt i only need one \?
alert(JSON.stringify({abspath:'U:\path'})); //wtf
alert(JSON.stringify({abspath:'U:\\path'}));//wtf2
//alert(JSON.stringify({abspath:'U:/path'}));//different
alert(JSON.stringify({abspath:"U:\path"}));  //even here!?
alert(JSON.stringify({abspath:"U:\\path"})); //fuuuuuuuuuuuuu
```

Comment: You're probably forgetting that the stringified version will have \\ even though the actual string will just have \. Because of escaping. After all, `\t` is tab, but `\p` doesn't mean anything at all.

Comment: @AnthonyMills: I feel a bit silly now. Yes thats correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the script outputs `{"abspath":"U:\\path"}`, that is a valid JSON string. It doesn't **look** like a valid object because it is still escaped -- JSON string aren't intended to be human-readable.

If you were to decode that string, you would end up with the desired value. Your output is still escaped, as it should be, pending decoding. If it was NOT escaped in the encoded string, you wouldn't be able to decode it.

See happen: http://jsfiddle.net/dhzMQ/1/ (requires availability of `console`)

**Further Reading**

- JSON spec - http://www.json.org/
- Escaping examples - http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EscapingExamples

Comment: ah ha, the alert was fooling me. I feel a bit stupid i forgot that

Answer (score 3):

```
alert( JSON.stringify({abspath:"U:\\path"}) )
```

This is corrrect, you need `\\` in JSON format because that is how \ is stored.

You can tell by parsing that JSON and querying abspath.

```
alert(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({abspath:"U:\\path"})).abspath); 
alert( JSON.stringify({abspath:"U:\\path"}) )
```

Answer (score 2):

The string stored in the object:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"abspath": "U:\\path"})).abspath
```

...has only one `\`.

Comment: No problem.  I starting working on it before there were any comments, but by the time I finished I saw you had plenty of correct answers.  Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

valid JSON has quotes around the key and the value

```
{"abspath":"U:\\path"}
```

Works for me

```
JSON.stringify({"abspath":"U:\\path"});
```

Comment: True, but he isn't putting in JSON to be stringified he is putting in an object. Double quotes are not required in objects.